# docker compose override a ports property instead of merging it

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

My docker compose configs look like this:

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:
    nginx:
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
```

docker-compose.prod.yml

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:
    nginx:
        ports:
            - 80:80
```

Now, when I run command: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up` the nginx exposes on host machine two ports: `8000` and `80`, because it merges ports properties:

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:
    nginx:
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
            - 80:80
```

Is there a way to override it? I want to expose only port `80`.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This behaviour is documented at https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#adding-and-overriding-configuration

> For the multi-value options `ports`, `expose`, `external_links`, `dns`, `dns_search`, and `tmpfs`, Compose concatenates both sets of values

Since the `ports` will be the concatenation of the ports in all your compose files, I would suggest creating a new `docker-compose.dev.yml` file which contains your development port mappings, removing them from the base `docker-compose.yml` file.

As [Nikson says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48853245), you can name this `docker-compose.override.yml` to apply your development configuration automatically without chaining the docker-compose files. `docker-compose.override.yml` will not be applied if you manually specify another override file (e.g. `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml`)

Answer (score 6):

Just keep the `docker-compose.yml` super simple and add the ports in another file `docker-compose.develop.yml`, then run it like `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.develop.yml up`.
This way you can separate it from your `docker-compose.override.yml` file.

So you will have three files:

```
|- docker-compose.yml # no ports specified
|- docker-compose.override.yml # ports 8080:8080
|- docker-compose.develop.yml #ports 80:80
```

Refer to this post for longer explanation: https://mindbyte.nl/2018/04/04/overwrite-ports-in-docker-compose.html

Comment: This requires you to specify `-f docker-compose.develop.yml` on every command you run also on dev.

Answer (score 4):

it isn't possible a the moment but I found quite good way to fix this issue using the command [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq).
You need to remove the ports from the original file.

**Example:**
Be careful this command will remove the nginx ports from your current docker-compose.yml (because of the -i option)

```sh
yq e -i 'del(.services.nginx.ports)' docker-compose.yml
```

You can execute this command on your deployment script or manually before your `docker-compose up -d`

There's also an open [issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3729) on docker-compose, that you may want to check once in a while.

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible through `docker-compose.override.yml` file using the `!override` modifier.

```
services:
  nginx:
    ports: !override
      - "80:80"
```

Source: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/13-merge/#replace-value

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem. The proposed solution with `docker-compose.override.yml` sounds pretty well and is also an official one.

Although for some of my own projects I've applied the `erb` template engine to make `docker-compose.yml.erb` file compile for multiple environments. In short I use:

```
COMPOSE_TEMPLATE_ENV=production erb docker-compose.yml.erb > docker-compose.yml
COMPOSE_TEMPLATE_ENV=production erb docker-compose.yml.erb > docker-compose-production.yml
```

And then I can use the `ENV['COMPOSE_TEMPLATE_ENV']` in my template and also the syntax of `ERB`, so only one file to configure and no worries about piplening them properly. [Here's the short post article I've written about it](https://zinovyev.net/blog/configure-docker-compose-files-for-multiple-environments)

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this info maybe it will be helpful for somebody like me. I wanted to remove the ports that were set in docker-compose.yml by setting in the docker-compose.override.yml this:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  nginx:
    ports: !reset []
```

As described in this [article](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/13-merge/#replace-value).

Answer (score -5):

Use `.override.yml` file for overriding properties and a clear separation of properties need to be overridden

```
docker-compose.override.yml
```

Example:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
    nginx:
        ports:
            - 80:80
```

Default:

```
docker-compose up
```

will use your `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.override.yml` files

Reference: [docker-compose multiple compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files)

Comment: This doesn't solve their issue of the prod configuration receiving the concatenation of ports in the original and override file.

Comment: @RachSharp, he suggested to remove ports from `docker-compose.yml` and put them only in `docker-compose.override.yml`. So when you concat `docker-compose.yml` and docker-compose.prod.yml`, you'll get only prod ports.

Comment: Bit of a stretch, doesn't mention anything about removing ports from the `docker-compose.yml` or how to use port `8080` when not running on prod