# Host and port forwarding in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, squid, docker-network

Hopefully an expert in docker networking can help.

I have a django application that integrates with several third-party APIs. These APIs call-back to my application using a hardcoded URL - this means that the callbacks during testing and development use the production hostname and port. I.e. the callback goes to foo.com:443 but in development my app runs on localhost:8000.

I currently get around this by using squid (with a hosts file that maps foo.com to 127.0.0.1), and an iptables command that forwards port 443 to 8000. Then I connect my browser to squid and everything works.

**Now I am trying to include this proxy/port forwarding setup in my docker-compose environment.**

I already use docker-compose to launch the other services I use for development (postgres, redis, etc). I want to launch the proxy as well.

My current service in docker-compose:

```
proxy:
  network_mode: host
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: proxy.Dockerfile
```

The dockerfile for squid:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get install -y squid
COPY .squid.conf /squid/.squid.conf
COPY .squid_hosts /squid/.squid_hosts
CMD squid -N -f /squid/squid.conf
```

**But I still have to run iptables to forward 443 to 8000**

So at this point I could start hacking iptables into the squid container, and try to somehow discover the host ip address and forward 127.0.0.1:443 to <host_ip>:8000 but **surely docker's networking features can help me?**

I have a feeling that I'm doing it wrong, even with the custom hosts file for the squid instance, and that a lot of my problem can be solved on the docker-compose level?

**Summary: How can I run a proxy in docker, that when connected to with a browser will forward foo.com:443 to docker-host:8000**

**EDIT:**
I got it working using [socat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/socat) to do the port forwarding. So the container runs on a bridge network, with squid as a proxy - squid has a hosts file that sends foo.com to 127.0.0.1 (localhost on the container). Then I listen to port 443 in the container with socat - and relay traffic to 8000 on the host.

So it works. Still waiting for a docker guru to tell me how i'm doing it wrong though :|

Comment: you can use `--network host` then docker will use your Host netork and can connect to your localhost:8000, or you meant something else ?

Comment: @LinPy When I browse to foo.com:443 with a browser connected to the squid instance in docker - I want the requests to end up on the host:8000

Comment: and where is that host:8000 ?

Comment: @LinPy I mean the docker host machine.

Comment: take a look also in `-p` option in Docker to setup listening ports

Comment: look at the example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851190/docker-compose-override-a-ports-property-instead-of-merging-it/48863743#48863743) where they use a `ports` mapping. You can have an entry like `443:8000`

Comment: An easier workaround for needing to use hardcoded callback URLs might be to either, register a separate app/callback that forwards to localhost, for development. Or if on unix you could put a forwarding rule in your `/etc/hosts` so that on your machine, `localhost:8000` is treated as `foobar.com`. With either of these you don't need a proxy container just for rewriting URL (although you still might want it so that testing locally reflects how it will work on prod)

Comment: @RachSharp yes, `/etc/hosts` works to make foo.com=127.0.0.1, but cannot be used to map the port - iptables must be used for that. But in my case I want to be able to access the "real" foo.com as well (and the dev, staging and testing envs) This is why the proxy server is needed - so I can run a proxy server (in docker) for each env, and when I connect the browser to it - foo.com will be the correct environment.